# Disable ion-range when condition is met

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to disable the ion-range while scrolling the page ,im going to detect the ion content scroll with

```
(ionScroll)="onScroll($event)"
```

than i would call a function to disable the ion-range, is there an attribute for disabling it? i didnt find it in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an input with type="range" and the ng-disable directive. Something like this:

```
<input type="range" name="[name]" ng-disabled="[your-condition]">
```

Maybe this post in ionic forum could help more.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/disable-range-selection-with-toggle/26027

Hope it helps!